# Display value of the Dictionary in C#

Tags: c#

I have this code and I have a problem with the `Debug.Log` it does not show the values of the `Dictionary` as I need to double check my work when I run this C# on unity the following message appears

> System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String] UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)

```
public Dictionary<char, List<string>> wordsMap;

void ProcessWordSource (string data) {

    var words = data.Split('\n');
    foreach (var entry in words) 
    {
        var c = entry[0];
        if (!wordsMap.ContainsKey(c))
        {
            wordsMap.Add (c, new List<string>());
        }
        wordsMap[c].Add(entry.TrimEnd());
    }
    foreach (var pair in wordsMap)
    {
        Debug.Log(pair.Value.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this problem solved?

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to flatten out that inner `List<string>` to view it properly, and [`String.Join`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx) can help you with that:

```
Debug.Log(string.Join(", ", pair.Value));
```

If you're using a version of the .NET Framework that doesn't support passing a `List<T>` to this method, you may have to convert it to an array first.

```
Debug.Log(string.Join(", ", pair.Value.ToArray()));
```

The value in your Dictionary is a collection, and what you're seeing (the type of the collection) when you call `ToString()` on it is normal. In fact, any object that doesn't override `ToString()` defaults to the base [`Object.ToString()` method](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/object.cs,4d73eb225aef8a61), which simply outputs the type:

```
// Returns a String which represents the object instance. The default
// for an object is to return the fully qualified name of the class.
public virtual String ToString()
{
    return GetType().ToString();
}
```

Comment: thanks man but i tried and here what i get  **The best overloaded method match for `string.Join(string, string[])' has some invalid arguments  ** error CS1503: Argument `#2' cannot convert `System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' expression to type `string[]' thank u

Comment: What Framework Version are you using? Does `Debug.Log(String.Join(", ", pair.Value.ToArray()));` work?

Comment: The `IEnumerable<T>` version of [String.Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd992421.aspx) (which `List<string>` would use) is "new" in .Net 4. -- maybe mono.net 4 is not aware of it, yet.

Comment: thanks a lot even the String is case senstevie i used string not String however i am using mono developer for unity 5.1.3 the framework is 4 for .net thanks again.